# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string,

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, ora-01861

Currently I am trying to compare date fields with the below statement

```
AND (AIA.INVOICE_DATE >= NVL(TO_DATE(:P_INV_DT_FROM,'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-1900')  
OR AIA.INVOICE_DATE IS NULL)
AND (AIA.INVOICE_DATE <= NVL(TO_DATE(:P_INV_DT_TO,'DD-MON-YYYY'), '31-DEC-4712')  
OR AIA.INVOICE_DATE IS NULL)
```

However, I am getting the below error,

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>
> *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

P.S: AIA.INVOICE_DATE is tn the form of 'DD-MON-YYYY' and p_inv_dt_from and p_inv_dt_to is in the form of 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS'

Comment: These are not date values: `'01-JAN-1900'`, `'31-DEC-4712'`

Comment: Also, if `AIA.INVOICE_DATE` has any "format", it must be a string, not a date column.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly identify the format of '01-JAN-1900' and '31-DEC-4712' (that is wrap them in TO_DATE('01-JAN-1900','DD-MON-YYYY')).  Otherwise, Oracle will attempt to convert the strings to a date based on the environment session settings of whoever is running the code.  Your session, for instance, may have NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY', which isn't compatible with '01-JAN-1900'.